How does Indonesia apply the "At least six months passport validity" rule?
My passport expires on 28/02/2025 and I am planning to enter Indonesia, which has a requirement of "at least 6 months from entry", on 31/08/2024. Timatic and TravelDoc both say I am okay, but I just wanted to confirm that because of the way calendar months work, I will be fine to enter.

what are the countries?

"I just wanted to confirm that because of the way calendar months work, I will be fine to enter": different countries may interpret "six months" differently.  To answer precisely, we would need to know the country you're entering.  Even then, it may be difficult or impossible to find out specifically how that country interprets "six months," but without knowing what country it is we certainly won't be able to help.

The country is Indonesia

That’s really cutting it to the wire… What happens if there is a delay and you end up arriving the next day?

Why don’t you avoid any risk and just get a new passport?

@jcaron: are the six months about that uncertainty and delays?

@GiacomoCatenazzi I mean when entering the country… if OP arrives a day late they might refuse entry (depending on how they count)
